# Angular 8 PWA assetGroups offline not working

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I made an Angular 8.1.0 PWA and when I test it offline on my mobile device the images and font in the assetGroups are not loading.

Here an example error for the logo image from chrome://inspect from the installed app on the offline mobile device, thrown from ngsw-worker.js:596

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for https://exampledomain.com/assets/logo.svg returned response 504 Gateway Timeout
    at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous>
```

Here the ngws-config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the ngws-config.json after the production build:

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "timestamp": 1563173692955,
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/main-es2015.689aadc303f18e627b86.js",
        "/main-es5.ee2fe89fd9715359423f.js",
        "/polyfills-es2015.bfe445a5fe4a078e3bd7.js",
        "/polyfills-es5.2219c87348e60efc0076.js",
        "/runtime-es2015.703a23e48ad83c851e49.js",
        "/runtime-es5.465c2333d355155ec5f3.js",
        "/styles.0d6b774b440b874b07f5.css"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/3405E1_0_0.254f1b554f08928edbfe.eot",
        "/3405E1_0_0.4eec58f7f58d86d0136f.woff",
        "/3405E1_0_0.89f2e03e5be552d187b0.ttf",
        "/3405E1_0_0.a140c5d9ff48f89cd132.woff2",
        "/3405E1_1_0.1141c29a5ace938968de.woff2",
        "/3405E1_1_0.8ae86c2030df85a73353.ttf",
        "/3405E1_1_0.a2374906ddbb8fe33667.eot",
        "/3405E1_1_0.c64c469afa8f5fbccafe.woff",
        "/3405E1_2_0.08521d75558d4817ba99.woff2",
        "/3405E1_2_0.746af6d254502ae02a0f.eot",
        "/3405E1_2_0.8675b352e8d358a4c75e.ttf",
        "/3405E1_2_0.fffce226c716355dc60e.woff",
        "/3405E1_3_0.03a6a6be22f367008456.ttf",
        "/3405E1_3_0.18c23e244175591d938b.woff",
        "/3405E1_3_0.5e0459024c2bdb4f46cc.woff2",
        "/3405E1_3_0.984e51e63d090e3b758d.eot",
        "/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
        "/assets/logo.svg",
        "/assets/ok.svg",
        "/assets/pfeil-links.svg",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.eot",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.ttf",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.woff",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.woff2",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.eot",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.ttf",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.woff",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.woff2",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.eot",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.ttf",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.woff",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.woff2",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.eot",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.ttf",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.woff",
        "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.woff2"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [],
  "hashTable": {
    "/3405E1_0_0.254f1b554f08928edbfe.eot": "390e70b65a28230070b11874c42fc29a38c50305",
    "/3405E1_0_0.4eec58f7f58d86d0136f.woff": "fca72e038d5c9b823102557ac64895d6e64488a9",
    "/3405E1_0_0.89f2e03e5be552d187b0.ttf": "143629b1399abe0a95305a0ad6bf1e22630127a3",
    "/3405E1_0_0.a140c5d9ff48f89cd132.woff2": "5ed39fae6e54175097262f330d8afb9c44e437ba",
    "/3405E1_1_0.1141c29a5ace938968de.woff2": "dff11d5ad9fb029d3f3d4f3c7c0756913d8f98b5",
    "/3405E1_1_0.8ae86c2030df85a73353.ttf": "05c376f1c66105d9924fd0766f6ed02350c24c6a",
    "/3405E1_1_0.a2374906ddbb8fe33667.eot": "f7a9c6b7fba08557b2e85d03c2f84b675958a491",
    "/3405E1_1_0.c64c469afa8f5fbccafe.woff": "4d52d09c75893a06d90f83d40aa1e6635d5d819d",
    "/3405E1_2_0.08521d75558d4817ba99.woff2": "4d0c71ef36e3c47eb95670031118c89c99de61e8",
    "/3405E1_2_0.746af6d254502ae02a0f.eot": "dd1fbdde450c5d3757067ea1bfc7db986cfa002b",
    "/3405E1_2_0.8675b352e8d358a4c75e.ttf": "f09530997b2bd02003dcec309bdf2f1608b0925b",
    "/3405E1_2_0.fffce226c716355dc60e.woff": "81333bd973c221f0db0251169d0c8f20cb8a0add",
    "/3405E1_3_0.03a6a6be22f367008456.ttf": "4e0e7ee61da3e9842b7816e0ae637af95dd999a6",
    "/3405E1_3_0.18c23e244175591d938b.woff": "4553f17cd805b00e9e74cea96417f03408d582a5",
    "/3405E1_3_0.5e0459024c2bdb4f46cc.woff2": "41ada2bd9b5f3f6ed8722075b571734e36591f85",
    "/3405E1_3_0.984e51e63d090e3b758d.eot": "b8a28de51a31444272bcdc57f78ebd0e648b51c7",
    "/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png": "dae3b6ed49bdaf4327b92531d4b5b4a5d30c7532",
    "/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png": "b0bd89982e08f9bd2b642928f5391915b74799a7",
    "/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png": "7479a9477815dfd9668d60f8b3b2fba709b91310",
    "/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png": "1abd80d431a237a853ce38147d8c63752f10933b",
    "/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png": "329749cd6393768d3131ed6304c136b1ca05f2fd",
    "/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png": "559d9c4318b45a1f2b10596bbb4c960fe521dbcc",
    "/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png": "c457e56089a36952cd67156f9996bc4ce54a5ed9",
    "/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png": "3914125a4b445bf111c5627875fc190f560daa41",
    "/assets/logo.svg": "6c6c23943032ddbaf58cc57831ffdeccc1e42a50",
    "/assets/ok.svg": "0cf100e30624ac5024757308b95ed6ba85b2d052",
    "/assets/pfeil-links.svg": "e4b2ba69650f9aa33f1b5c82308259b4cb200a58",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.eot": "390e70b65a28230070b11874c42fc29a38c50305",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.ttf": "143629b1399abe0a95305a0ad6bf1e22630127a3",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.woff": "fca72e038d5c9b823102557ac64895d6e64488a9",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_0_0.woff2": "5ed39fae6e54175097262f330d8afb9c44e437ba",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.eot": "f7a9c6b7fba08557b2e85d03c2f84b675958a491",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.ttf": "05c376f1c66105d9924fd0766f6ed02350c24c6a",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.woff": "4d52d09c75893a06d90f83d40aa1e6635d5d819d",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_1_0.woff2": "dff11d5ad9fb029d3f3d4f3c7c0756913d8f98b5",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.eot": "dd1fbdde450c5d3757067ea1bfc7db986cfa002b",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.ttf": "f09530997b2bd02003dcec309bdf2f1608b0925b",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.woff": "81333bd973c221f0db0251169d0c8f20cb8a0add",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_2_0.woff2": "4d0c71ef36e3c47eb95670031118c89c99de61e8",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.eot": "b8a28de51a31444272bcdc57f78ebd0e648b51c7",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.ttf": "4e0e7ee61da3e9842b7816e0ae637af95dd999a6",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.woff": "4553f17cd805b00e9e74cea96417f03408d582a5",
    "/assets/webfonts/3405E1_3_0.woff2": "41ada2bd9b5f3f6ed8722075b571734e36591f85",
    "/favicon.ico": "84161b857f5c547e3699ddfbffc6d8d737542e01",
    "/index.html": "f4c6f13900643ba464e6a5b1f1e41389e7e55bdd",
    "/main-es2015.689aadc303f18e627b86.js": "017a58d40df6a948f8ddd0e7d91538559e3d5536",
    "/main-es5.ee2fe89fd9715359423f.js": "5efc5443bfcefcc7a66ea3a575d59c05673f2f0f",
    "/polyfills-es2015.bfe445a5fe4a078e3bd7.js": "fa3294dc18f74d99ffb7812c33dbbdb3daf098ca",
    "/polyfills-es5.2219c87348e60efc0076.js": "6c9688c6586bfcf669879655ba5874ef1d2b4bcf",
    "/runtime-es2015.703a23e48ad83c851e49.js": "b62956c2192bfe5516d6374e753773901ed50ec5",
    "/runtime-es5.465c2333d355155ec5f3.js": "b62956c2192bfe5516d6374e753773901ed50ec5",
    "/styles.0d6b774b440b874b07f5.css": "c232e470a48247d386d4d14d1bfe66a97c9d125d"
  },
  "navigationUrls": [
    {
      "positive": true,
      "regex": "^\\/.*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the manifest.webmanifest

```
{
  "name": "testClient",
  "short_name": "testClient",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

And it is also interesting that if start the app when I'am online and go then offline it works. But if I start the app offline then the images and fonts are not loaded. The css is always ok.

Thanks!

[image: img dev tool]

Comment: I also tested now on a another device and it's the same problem ...

Comment: also put the problem to gitHub https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31581#issuecomment-511764897

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution ?

Comment: @Spawnrad no I could not figured it out, check out the github link there I posted all the steps I tried ...

Answer (score 0):

The service worker has to be registered a first time in order to be able to provide the assets from the cache.

When you say that you "start the app from offline", can you check that the SW is correctly running on your side? You can verify this in the Application Tab of DevTools.
If theSW is registered, can you also verify that the images are cached?

I created an [Angular PWA demo](https://github.com/pacoita/angular-pwa-boilerplate) if you want to have a look at it and compare with your code. The demo code uses AssetGroups to store some images and DataGroups to cache API requests. I also wrote some tech articles about it, if interested:

- [Service workers explained](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f)
- [Angular PWAs caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular)

---

**UPDATE**

Using the link you posted, I can see that the two svg files are correctly cached:

[image]

Comment: Hello Francesco, thanks for your replay ... it's strange i can see the file in the Application -> Cache Storage but console throws an error that the image can not be loadet. The SW try to load it from the url. The Error is: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for https://exampledomain.com/assets/logo.svg returned response 504

Comment: should it be loaded from the cache?

Comment: And by inspecting the service worker I found also this warning: The FetchEvent for "https://exampledomain.com/assets/logo.svg" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.

Comment: If the assets are in the cache, the service worker should be the request initiator and provide them from the cache. You use "installMode": "prefetch" also for the assets, but if you have many images that do not change frequently, you could use a lazy strategy in this case. Eventually target specific assets that you want available since the beginning in the "app" group, as this is usually reserved for the resources that build the "app shell". Could you try to compare your files with my demo to detect any differences?

Comment: ahhh I just figured out that only .svg images are not loaded, i convert the svg's to png's and now it works fine. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: and I tried it with your demo code and it's the same ... the svg files are not cached

Comment: Good, one step forward!! ".svg" are among the target extensions, therefore they should be loaded as the other images. I will check why this is not the case.

Comment: I tested it and the two svg images are also among the cached files. Aren't they cached on your side?

Comment: that's the strange thing, the are in the cache but got not loaded, i will add a screenshot of the dev tool

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with service worker in 3 files: `main.*.js`, `polyfill.*.js` and `runtime.*.js`. I am not sure if it was hashing algorytm mismatch, but what helped in my case was using target `es5` instead of `es2015` in `tsconfig.json`.